# How to address a python list in MySQL query with "WHERE"?

Tags: mysql, string, python-2.7

I have the below code in which I want my MySQL query select those values in the 'name' column that are identical to the value in 'filenames' python list. I keep get an empty () as for the result. Can anyone help me with this?

```
import MySQLdb
import fnmatch
import os
import pprint

connect = MySQLdb.connect(host = "123.5.4.4", port=3366, user = "me", passwd="*********", db="data2")

filenames=[]
maindict = {}  

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('d:/data1'):  
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.txt'):   
       filenames.append(filename)

with connect:            
    cur= connect.cursor()            
    cur.execute("SELECT version,name FROM data2.files WHERE name IN ('filenames'.join('')" )
    result = cur.fetchall()

pprint.pprint(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
cur.execute(
    "SELECT version,name FROM data2.files WHERE name IN (" +
    ",".join(("%s",) * len(filenames)) + 
    ")",
    tuple(filenames)
)
```

This creates a SQL string of the form

```
WHERE name IN (%s,%s,%s,%s)
```

with as many `%s`s you need and makes the MySQL module replace them with the `filenames` data, taking care of quoting as needed.

Comment: the result still is as empty ()

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
cur.execute("SELECT version,name FROM data2.files WHERE name IN ('filenames'.join('')" )
```

with:

```
cur.execute("SELECT version,name FROM data2.files WHERE name IN ('%s')" % "','".join(filenames) )
```

in python shell:

```
>>> filenames=['file1', 'file2']
>>> query = "SELECT version,name FROM data2.files WHERE name IN ('%s')" % "','".join(filenames)
>>> print query
SELECT version,name FROM data2.files WHERE name IN ('file1','file2')
>>>
```

Comment: It seems that there is an extra quotation in  your comment right?It isnot working with this either

Comment: may you can add a extra debug line which prints the resulting sql query. then fire the resulting sql in a mysql shell.

Comment: It is a syntax problem now. Is the syntax of the code you wrote correct?

Comment: i didn't try against a db. but see the python shell example above.

Comment: There are better ways. Yours is vulnerable to SQL injection.